# Why don't the changes to my variables survive until the next iteration?

Tags: c++, struct

I want to update instances of a `struct` that I am storing in a `map` within a loop, but the changes to the instance variables don't survive the iterations of the loop (within one iteration, the new variables get properly set, in the next operation they are reset to their initial value).

Here is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```
map<int, RegionOverFrames>* foundRegions = new map<int, RegionOverFrames>;

for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {

    // find all regions in current frame
    map<int, RegionOverFrames> regionsInCurrentFrame;
    for (Region region: currentFrame.regions) {
        if (foundRegions->count(region.regionId) == 0) {
            RegionOverFrames foundRegion;
            foundRegion.regionId = region.regionId;
            regionsInCurrentFrame[region.regionId] = foundRegion;
            (*foundRegions)[region.regionId] = foundRegion;
        }
        else if (foundRegions->count(region.regionId) > 0) {
            RegionOverFrames foundRegion = (*foundRegions)[region.regionId];
            regionsInCurrentFrame[region.regionId] = foundRegion;
        }
    }

    // update found regions (either by adding weight or setting the end index)
    for (auto it = foundRegions->begin(); it != foundRegions->end(); it++) {
        RegionOverFrames foundRegion = it->second;
        // the region that was found before is also present in this frame
        if (regionsInCurrentFrame.count(foundRegion.regionId) > 0) {
            float weight = currentFrame.getRegion(foundRegion.regionId).getWeight();
            foundRegion.accumulatedWeight += weight; // this update of accumulatedWeight is not present in the next loop, the accumulatedWeight only gets assigned the value of weight here, but in the next iteration it's reset to 0
        }
    }
}
```

Could it have something to do with the fact that I am using an iterator `it` to access the objects within my `map<int, RegionOverFrames>* foundRegions` or with the fact that `foundRegions` is declared with a pointer and stored on the heap?

Note `RegionOverFrames` is a simple `struct` looking like this:

```
struct RegionOverFrames {
   int regionId;
   double accumulatedWeight;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to have `map<int, RegionOverFrames> regionsInCurrentFrame;` declared inside the 1st for loop?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, I do need to have it there since I am doing some calculation based on these elements later within the same loop :/

Comment: @juanchopanza with "survive", I essentially mean that `accumulatedWeight` _does get increased_ by the value of `weight` in one iteration, but in the next iteration it's just reset to 0. so the value doesn't persist beyond iterations.

Comment: Got it. The double negative was too much for me this early in the morning. But I see you fixed it.

Comment: You're updating copies of values, not references to them. You should use a reference to the stuff you're getting from the iterators.

Comment: As a side-note, there's nothing in your example motivating building the external map on the heap.

Comment: @AmiTavory I know, I omitted that part to show only the relevant parts of the code. I need it to be created on the heap...

Comment: why the downvotes by the way? I'm a c++ novice, isn't that a legitimate question to ask? should I have asked differently or provided more info?

Comment: Can't answer about the downvotes, but, if I may, an observation about the question. In a language in which I wouldn't be proficient, I'd print stuff right before and after modifying stuff, and pinpoint the exact place where it doesn't stick. I'd then ask a way way simplified version with just this code. Your question, e.g., doesn't require the loop even. Perhaps that's what's annoyed people.

Comment: hmm... I did exactly what you described but I omitted the print statements from the code I posted. but that's how I tracked down the issue in the first place. about the loop, it might not be strictly necesary, yet I believe that it provides helpful context because it makes clear that the values get set but values aren't persisted over iterations... thanks for the feedback though. I think it's not a good style of using SO giving downvotes without any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are creating a copy of the found region rather than updating the object found in the map.

```
RegionOverFrames foundRegion = it->second;
//               ^ copy created
```

You should use references instead:

```
RegionOverFrames &foundRegion = it->second;
//               ^ use reference
```

Comment: thanks! I was suspected that it was something related to making copies of the instances, but being a novice to C++ I couldn't figure out what exactly went wrong! :)

Comment: I can't see how using references to iterators would make a difference. In fact, it would give you dangling references because `begin()` returns by value.

Comment: by the way, I can't assign `auto &it = foundRegions->begin()`, this gives the following error: `error: non-const lvalue reference to type '__map_iterator<[...]>' cannot bind to a temporary of type '__map_iterator<[...]>'`

Comment: @nburk Yes, that makes sense. But you could use a range based loop instead: `for (auto& p : *foundRegions) { /* p is a ref to an element of the map */ }`

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the hint! I am now using your code and then use            `RegionOverFrames foundRegion = p.second;` to get access to the actual instance. but the values still don't survive. does `p.second` still return a copy?

Comment: @nburk the `auto& p` part means you have references to the pairs stored in the map. `p.second` itself is an lvalue. Modifying it modifies the element in the map directly. Which makes me thing maybe you're copying it inadvertently by some other means.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks! I got it to work now by using `RegionOverFrames &foundRegion = p.second;` and using a reference to the instance I want to modify. Guess that was the missing piece! Thanks a lot for your help. If you  add your hints as an answer, I'll accept it as a solution since your hints overall were the ones that were putting together the solution for me!

Comment: @nburk Glad it helped. I think the answer above should also give the required behaviour (after the edit.)